# addr2line produces question mark for line number

Tags: linux, grpc, addr2line

Recently while using `addr2line` for `gRPC` code I saw that it is not producing line number. The man page of `add2line` states that line number will be `0` if it can't determine.

```
$ addr2line -s -C -i -f -e mybin 0x85fbc2 0x7f9eacbcf330 0x7f9eacbcb402 0x7f9eaac826fc 0xa5f861 0x80862f
afunc
mymain.cpp:150
??
??:0
??
??:0
??
??:0
grpc::Server::Wait()
??:?                 <--- Problem
RunServer(void*)
server_grpc.cpp:94
```

What could be the reason for that `?` for the line number ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I saw question marks instead of line numbers when I passed the directory with compiled so files rather than obj/local

Comment: No, I am parsing the output to filter out question marks.